# KivyMD close the MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

Tags: python, kivymd

I have added a MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial to my project, and it works fine.  But I want it to close after the user has clicked one of the buttons.  I can't find anything in the documentation about how to achieve this.

I have tried setting the widgets state to 'close' but this produces odd behavior.  The buttons begin moving around the screen.

kv file

```
<ScreenDrawPlay>
    PaintingWidget:
        id: paint_canvas

    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        id: draw_float_button
        data: app.draw_button_data
        root_button_anim: True
        #hint_animation: True
        #on_touch_up: self.state = 'close'
        callback: app.draw_float_pressed
```

function

```
    def draw_float_pressed(self, instance):
        #print(instance.icon)
        self.screen_draw_play.ids.draw_float_button.state = 'close'
        if instance.icon == 'palette':
            self.color_dialog_open()
        elif instance.icon == 'check':
            self.upload_turn()
```

Answer (score 2):

So after looking through the KivyMD source, it looks like the proper way to do this is to call...

```
.close_stack()
```

the .state property is just for reading to find the current state